# Can not get the validation message when wrong file is uploaded using Angular.js ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have an issue while trying to implement `ng-file-upload` of Angular.js and my problem is i am not getting any validation message while uploading wrong file.My explaining my code below.

```
<form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
   <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-show="status==1">
        <div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.bannerimage.$touched && billdata.bannerimage.$invalid }">
        <div class="image-upload text-center">
        <label for="imagefile1">
        <img ng-src="{{attchImage1}}" style="cursor:pointer;width:auto; height:160px; border:1px #666 solid"/>
        </label>
<input type="file"  data-size="lg" name="bannerimage" id="imagefile1"  ng-model="file" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-min-height="100" ngf-resize="{width:100, height:100}"   custom-on-change="uploadFile"  ngf-select="onFileSelect($file);" >
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
        <label for="imagefile1" >
        <span style="color:#00F; font-style:italic; cursor:pointer"> Click here to upload Image </span>
    <input type="hidden" name="someData" ng-model="imageData" />
      </label>
</div>

 </div>
 </div>

</div>
 <div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.bannerimage.$error" ng-if="billdata.bannerimage.$touched">
<p ng-message="maxSize" style="color:#F00;">File is too large.Max size is 2 mb.</p>
<p ng-message="minHeight" style="color:#F00;">Minimum height should be 100px</p>
</div>

</form>
```

Here when i am uploading the wrong file size(`i.e-min-height<100px`) the validation error message should display but its not coming at all.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can we have a Fiddle of the same ?

Comment: do you have angular-messages.js loaded?

Comment: @Bonatoc : Yes, I have ` <script src="js/angular-messages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: what does console.log(billdata. bannerimage.$error) says ?

Comment: "When any of the validation directives specified the form validation will take place and you can access the value of the validation using myForm.myFileInputName.$error.<validate error name> for example form.file.$error.pattern. If multiple file selection is allowed you can specify ngf-model-invalid="invalidFiles" to assing the invalid files to a model and find the error of each individual file with file.$error and description of it with file.$errorParam. You can use angular ng-model-options to allow invalid files to be set to the ng-model ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}".

Comment: @Bonatoc : it is showing ` {minHeight: true}` in console.

Comment: so I assume you test to produce an error message on the height? I think it means : "error on minheight". It's an object because you can have multiple validation errors on the same input field.

Comment: @Bonatoc : Yes,please check my parameter set for the check error inside input type file.

Comment: Again,  {minHeight: true} means "yes, there's an error on minheight validation". After that, it's up to you I guess, to display the error.

Comment: Use ` ng-messages="billdata.bannerimage.$errorMessages"` see https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1335